# What do first for SEO activity?

Tags: seo

I'm newbie in SEO tasking but I motivate to be SEO master. I have done create any website. So, whats do the best first for SEO activity for good SEO in the future? How long any website can be high PageRank?

Comment: Vote to close question. Not constructive and too broad/vague.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are willing to become a SEO master, you have to know the basic SEO facts like:

- What is *On Page Optimization* and *Off Page Optimization*? Just refer the answers for this question on Wikipedia or other SEO sites
- Then you have to know what is *white hat SEO*? What is *Negative SEO*? And what are *Backlinks*? I can't answer all of these questions here so just refer these terms on Google.

Don't do *Negative SEO* at any time because no search engines like *Negative SEO*. In order to become a master of SEO you have to refer many sites and videos. On YouTube there are several videos of Matt Cutts (who is the head of Google Web Scam team). Get knowledge from those videos. You also have to learn what is Google Penguin update and Panda update.

Your website will get high PageRank (PR) if you get more backlinks from high PageRank sites but be cautious that themes of those high PR sites must match your website's theme i.e. don't get backlinks from irrelevant sites. If number of backlinks increases your websites PR will also increases.

Also learn about Google's latest Penguin Update 2.0. Google Rolled it on 22nd of this month and nearly 2.3% of English-US queries affected...

Comment: Thank you john. I'll try to research and get some information from youtube and another web.